# Distance between two symmetric equations

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been requested to solve this problem:

*Compute the distance between the lines:*

$L_{1}:\frac{x-2}{3}=\frac{y-5}{2}=\frac{z-1}{-1}$ and $L_{2}:\frac{x-4}{-4}=\frac{y-5}{4}=\frac{z+2}{1}$

**This is my solution**:

I specify one point for each line:

$P_{L_{1}}=(5,7,0)$

$Q_{L_{2}}=(4,5,-2)$

To get a perpendicular vector:

$$\vec{w}=\vec{v_{1}}\times\vec{v_{2}}=\begin{vmatrix} i & j & k \\ 3 & 2 & - 1\\ - 4& 4 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=6i+j+20k$$

Parallel vector two those lines:

$\vec{PQ}=(4,5,-2)-(5,7,0)=-i-2j-2k$

Then I calculate the projection of $\vec{PQ}$ over $\vec{w}$:

$Proy_{(\vec{w})}(\vec{PQ})=-\frac{48}{\sqrt{437}}(6i+j+20k)$

Therefore, the distance between $L_{1}$ and $L_{2}$ is:

$\| Proy_{(\vec{w})}(\vec{PQ})\|=\frac{48}{\sqrt{437}}$

Is my calculation procedure correct?

Comment: Yes this is correct. You could have used $(2,5,1)$ for the first point

Comment: @DavidQuinn Could you please transform your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Workaholic, the solution already given by the OP is fine, though. I was merely pointing out that *any* points on the respective lines can be used in this way and the result is the same

Comment: @DavidQuinn That's not what I meant, I only stated that you should copy-paste your comment to make an answer for this question so that it no longer be in the 'unanswered' list.

Comment: @Workaholic I have posted my answer below

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is correct, although you could equally well have used the point $(2,5,1)$ as the chosen point on line $L_1$ and obtained the same result.

The general result is that the distance $d$ between the skew lines $\underline{r}=\underline{a_1}+\lambda\underline{b_1}$ and $\underline{r}=\underline{a_2}+\mu\underline{b_2}$ is given by $$d=\left|(\underline{a_2}-\underline{a_1})\cdot\underline{\hat{n}}\right|, $$ where $\underline{\hat{n}}$ is the unit vector parallel to $$\underline{b_1}\times\underline{b_2}$$